# Google Tag Assistant Reports " Same Web Property ID is tracked twice"

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have less than a <5% bounce rate on Google analytics at the moment which is abnormal.

I've read online this could be because of double google analytic tracking tags.

I've removed Google analytic tracking tags and instead kept Google Tag Manager.

However I'm still getting "Same Web Property ID is tracked down".

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me to the right direction, here is the URL https://ru9.vn/products/foam-nest?variant=34938761511063

Edit: All fixed. The problem for me was more then 1 page view firing under Google Tag Manager.

After getting rid of a few tags with page view tags, bounce rate levels went back to normal.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be fine now. Maybe try clearing your browser cache if you are still seeing the warning.

It is only showing 1 pageview and 1 event and no "Same Web Property ID is tracked twice" warning

Screencast of Tag Assistant when I checked site:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EliTWFJaUKtk8Ewpvvc8W08aR3NAy6T5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics tag is still visible in Google Tag assistant. Have a look at the Tag settings and remove the Analytics tag.

If it's a WordPress website this might help: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-wordpress-quit-inserting-paragraph-tags-28869.html

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If GA is deployed by GTM there will be a tag in Tag Assistant for GA unless the GA transport mechanism has been set to beacon